# What does the cookie potion message mean?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I made a cookie potion and used it during a combat, then a message alert appeared with this text:

> 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%3D%21END%21

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After taking a quick peek at the code, this is just the **intended behaviour** of a cookie potion and has no direct bearing at all.

---

## But wait, there is more!

This code got me curious, because it's a base64-encoded string of various values - similar to the save format - and similar to the (obviously-related) Cookie Clicker save format.

First step - Cleaning up at the end (`%3D` becomes `=`, and `%21END%21` is discarded - it would just be turned into `!END!`, to mark the end (duh!) of the code):

> 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

The above code is compatible with the [current version of Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) and results in the following game state:

[image: Cookie Clicker: Cookie Overflow Edition]

---

## But wait, there is more!

If we decode it from base64, we get this code:

> 1.0393||1378830632876;NaN;1383239138575|001100|1929852769.060055;706421271749.1023;8297;19;13825599421.881443;80;-1;-1;0;0;0;0;67;47969;0;0;0;0|128,129,7684536217,0;105,106,2376679320,0;101,101,54173598,0;101,101,239011981,1;82,82,613410826,0;58,58,1414881926,0;50,50,2831132572,0;50,50,40566625273,0;27,27,66454955460,0;16,16,227782320454,0;|4503599627370495;4503100337422335;2251834173401703;3940649673959935;2251799945805963;137438953473|4503047791083519;2392816740112091;1025

Importing this save in [Cookie Clicker Classic](http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/), results in an even fancier save state, as follows:

[image: Cookie Clicker Classic: Cookie Overflow Edition]

Comment: It's not similar to a save data format. It has to be something different =/

Comment: @SysDragon It is save data, just for a different game. Updating my answer as we speak.

Comment: Amazing discovering! O.o Wish I could upvote more than one

Comment: Wonderful! ... or you can also [ask him](http://www.reddit.com/r/thegoldfactory/comments/2airzl/few_questions/) xD

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I found this by searching my cookie clicker export data. This is a bit late, but that's the exact format every cookie clicker save code uses. I'm pretty sure that's a cookie clicker code :D, what a fun little easter egg.

It might not be similar to a save format code, but it's 100% similar to Cookie Clicker's save format code. Not to mention the name is "Cookie Potion", that cannot be a coincidence. :P

Best easter egg ever.